# awk extract columns from file based on header from second file 3

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to run some modified code from a previous thread on this subject.
I have a file data.txt where the first row is the header. I would like to create a new file with only those columns that match the entries from a second file (list.txt).

data.txt

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1.000000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,1.000000,0.031250,0,0,0,0.031250,0,0,0
0,0.031250,1.000000,0,0,0,0.062500,0,0,0
0,0,0,1.000000,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,1.000000,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,1.000000,0,0.062500,0,0
0,0.031250,0.062500,0,0,0,1.000000,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0.062500,0,1.000000,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1.000000,0
```

list.txt

```
3
5
7
9
```

Desired output is

```
3,5,7,9
0,0,0,0
0.031250,0,0.031250,0
1.000000,0,0.062500,0
0,0,0,0
0,1.000000,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,1.000000,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,1.000000
```

I have used the code below

```
echo "${DATAFILE:-data.txt}"
echo "${COLUMNFILE:-list.txt}"

awk {
     j=1
     while ((getline < COLUMNFILE) > 0) {
        col[j++] = $1
     }
     n=j-1;
     close(COLUMNFILE)
     for (i=1; i<=n; i++) s[col[i]]=i
   }
   NR==1 {
     for (f=1; f<=NF; f++)
       if ($f in s) c[s[$f]]=f
     next
   }
   { sep=","
     for (f=1; f<=n; f++) {
       printf("%c%s",sep,$c[f])
       sep=FS
     }
     print ""
 } 
 DATAFILE
```

I get the result below which is duplicating the rows in data.txt and not doing any selection. The entries from list.txt are printing at the end of the file

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1.000000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1.000000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

0,1.000000,0.031250,0,0,0,0.031250,0,0,0
0,1.000000,0.031250,0,0,0,0.031250,0,0,0

0,0.031250,1.000000,0,0,0,0.062500,0,0,0
0,0.031250,1.000000,0,0,0,0.062500,0,0,0

0,0,0,1.000000,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,1.000000,0,0,0,0,0,0

0,0,0,0,1.000000,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,1.000000,0,0,0,0,0

0,0,0,0,0,1.000000,0,0.062500,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,1.000000,0,0.062500,0,0

0,0.031250,0.062500,0,0,0,1.000000,0,0,0
0,0.031250,0.062500,0,0,0,1.000000,0,0,0

0,0,0,0,0,0.062500,0,1.000000,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0.062500,0,1.000000,0,0

0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1.000000,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1.000000,0

3
3

5
5

7
7

9
9
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `awk` cannot "see" the external vars, DATA/COLUMN FILE. you need to pass those in, ie. `awk -v COLF="$COLF" '{ awk program}' "$DATAFILE"` . I haven't looked closely at the rest of your code, but what you have seems like a good attempt. Good luck.

Comment: Using `getline` is rarely the right approach and certainly isn't in this case. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for when you should consider using `getline` and all of the caveats.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    NR==FNR { f[++nf]=$0; next }
    { for (i=1; i<=nf; i++) printf "%s%s", $(f[i]), (i<nf?OFS:ORS) }
' list.txt data.txt
3,5,7,9
0,0,0,0
0.031250,0,0.031250,0
1.000000,0,0.062500,0
0,0,0,0
0,1.000000,0,0
0,0,0,0
0.062500,0,1.000000,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,1.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass both your position file and your data file into awk and do your logic internally:

```
 awk -F"," 'FILENAME=="list.txt"{a[NR]=$1}FILENAME=="data.txt"{for(i=1; i<=length(a); i++){printf (i==length(a)?"%s\n":"%s,"),$a[i]}}' list.txt data.txt
```

Here we are:

1. Splitting incoming files with a comma delimiter (`-F","`)
2. If the FILENAME awk variable is "list.txt" (`FILENAME=="list.txt"`)
3. ++Then add the value in the line to an array using the line number as the index (`a[NR]=$1`)
4. If the FILENAME awk variable is "data.txt" (`FILENAME=="data.txt"`)
5. ++Then loop through each element in the array `for(i=1; i<=length(a); i++)`
6. ++++And print out the value of the item at that position (`$a[i]`). If the position is the last position found (`i==length(a)`) then print it out with a line feed following (`"%s\n"`) otherwise print it out with a comma following (`$a[i]`).

The other option is to pass in your positions via the -v (variable) flag, but this doesn't account well for a variable number of positions:

```
awk -F"," -v f1=$(awk 'NR==1' list.txt) -v f2=$(awk 'NR==2' list.txt) -v f3=$(awk 'NR==3' list.txt) -v f4=$(awk 'NR==4' list.txt) '{print $f1, $f2, $f3, $f4}' data.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

**awk** solution:

```
awk -F, 'function pr(a){ r=""; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(i in a) r=(r!="")? r","$i:$i; print r }
         NR==FNR{ a[$0]; next }{ pr(a) }' list.txt data.txt
```

The output:

```
3,5,7,9
0,0,0,0
0.031250,0,0.031250,0
1.000000,0,0.062500,0
0,0,0,0
0,1.000000,0,0
0,0,0,0
0.062500,0,1.000000,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,1.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

a non `awk` solution to compare and contrast...

```
$ join -t, <(sort list) <(<file tr ',' '\n' | pr -10ts, | sort) | 
  sort -n | 
  tr ',' '\n' | 
  pr -4ts,


3,5,7,9
0,0,0,0
0.031250,0,0.031250,0
1.000000,0,0.062500,0
0,0,0,0
0,1.000000,0,0
0,0,0,0
0.062500,0,1.000000,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,1.000000
```

you need the magic numbers `10` and `4` which are the column numbers of the original file and extracted ones (those can be automated as well).  Multiple sorts required to convert numerical sorting to lexicographical and back (required for `join`).

The algorithm in essence is `transpose`-`join`-`transpose`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an awk that processes the `list.txt` to a field list and calls another awk with that list to process the `data.txt`:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }          # set the delimiters for the list file
NR==FNR {                     # process the list file
    p=p (p==""?"":OFS) "$" $1 # make a field list ($3,$5,$7,$9)
    next
}
{                             # process the data or call the processor
    RS=""                     # for getline to return multilined output
    cmd="awk \047BEGIN{FS=OFS=\",\"}{print "p"}\047 " FILENAME   # build awk call
    cmd | getline res         # actual awk call and output to res
    print res                 # output res
    exit                      # exit after first record
}
' list data
3,5,7,9
0,0,0,0
0.031250,0,0.031250,0
1.000000,0,0.062500,0
0,0,0,0
0,1.000000,0,0
0,0,0,0
0.062500,0,1.000000,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,1.000000
```

Comment: creative but this is more in awk spirit `awk -f <(awk ...list.txt) file.txt`

Comment: I used the awk code awk -F"," 'FILENAME=="list.txt"{a[NR]=$1}FILENAME=="data.txt"{for(i=1; i<=length(a); i++){printf (i==length(a)?"%s\n":"%s,"),$a[i]}}' list.txt data.tx

Comment: and this worked very well on a data.txt with 100,000 lines and a list file of 5,000. Thanks for all suggestions

Answer (score 0):

awk solution, taking into account that columnnames can be anything, not only the index of the columns.

```
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR==FNR { l[$0]++; next }                      # save headers from list
FNR==1{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) 
            if ($i in l){ max=i; c[i]++ }}         # save column index in c;
                                                   # max index in max 
{ for(j=1; j<=NF; j++)                             # loop over column indices
      if(j in c)                                   # if index in c
          printf "%s%s", $j, (j==max ? ORS : OFS)  # print column
}
```

with input:

```
$ cat list.txt
C
E
G
I
```

and

```
$ cat data.txt
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J
1.000000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,1.000000,0.031250,0,0,0,0.031250,0,0,0
0,0.031250,1.000000,0,0,0,0.062500,0,0,0
0,0,0,1.000000,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,1.000000,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,1.000000,0,0.062500,0,0
0,0.031250,0.062500,0,0,0,1.000000,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0.062500,0,1.000000,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1.000000,0
```

gives as result:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} NR==FNR{l[$0]++;next} FNR==1{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i in l){max=i; c[i]++}}{for (j=1;j<=NF;j++) if(j in c) printf "%s%s",$j,(j==max ?ORS:OFS) }' list.txt data.txt
C,E,G,I
0,0,0,0
0.031250,0,0.031250,0
1.000000,0,0.062500,0
0,0,0,0
0,1.000000,0,0
0,0,0,0
0.062500,0,1.000000,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,1.000000
```

Comment: `for (j in c)` will output the columns in random (typically hash) order, not necessarily the order they appear in either input file. That may or may not be desirable...

Comment: That applies to the headers as well.

Comment: ...and it can be prevented by `{ for (j=1; j<=NF; j++) if(j in c) printf "%s%s", $j, (j==max ? ORS : OFS) }`